# apex mail template: add text to json placeholder

Tags: json, oracle-apex

is it possible to append a piece of information (plain text) to a JSON object after following lines?

```
..
apex_json.write('TABLE_CONTENT', l_table_content);
apex_json.close_object;
l_content := apex_json.get_clob_output;
apex_json.free_output;
..
```

Comment: I would say no. ```APEX_JSON``` is just serial - it concatenates sections to the existing object. The ```close_object``` concatenates the finale closing bracket. Anything you add after that will cause an error since the result can no longer be a valid json object

Comment: I've been trying things to add/replace some of the key-val pairs but as you've said it raises error saying "expected eof, got { instead" :)

however, i'm still forcing my hand. currently trying to parse it then change and re-wrap it. 

is it futile?

Comment: It'll be quite a bit of work to parse and rebuild... . From oracle 19c onwards there is ```json_mergepatch``` in sql - that is probably the easiest